# Getting last 6 values from an multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a need to get the last 6 values from an multidimentional array, I was trying to do something like this

```
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $stats = array_shift($stats);
}
```

But then after the first array_shift I get the following error

```
PHP Warning: array_shift(): The argument should be an array
```

Are there any functions that could do this in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
$stats = array_slice($stats, -6);
```

The reason your code isn't working is because

1. [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) removes from the front of the array - so you'd end up with the first 6 removed, which is not the same as getting the last 6 unless your array has 12 items...
2. array_shift edits the array in place and returns the item it removed

Comment: The second of those reasons is why you get the warning - since you've got a multi-dimensional array, the first time through the loop `array_shift` returns you the first element of your multi-dimensional array, which is a (mono-dimensional) array. Calling `array_shift` on a mono-dimensional array returns the first value of  that array, so `$stats` is not an array after the second time through the loop. I'd expect you to get an error after `array_shift` has been called twice (i.e. in the 3rd iteration of the loop).

Comment: I am quoting a great comment from @neokio:

excited by this answer, i did a quick test of 100,000 iterations, comparing (a) end($arr);$key = key($arr);reset($arr); against (b) $key = key(array_slice($arr,-1,1,true)); ... which resulting in end() being MUCH faster! end() = 0.05326 seconds, array_slice = 8.506 seconds ... huh?? –  neokio Sep 26 '12 at 7:00

So means that array_slice is not very perfomant. 

U might try this one:
`for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $stats = array_shift($stats);
}`